# Core Plot skipped values Graph

Tags: iphone, core-plot

i'm trying to draw a Graph with a user-friendly timeline having every day/week (to be decided by time range) as a label at x-axis. However, the datasource values are given on another basis - there might be 10 entries one day and the eleventh comes in a month.

See the photoshop image:

[image: timeline graph]

With the latest Core Plot drop I cannot find a way to do it, need your help.

Regards,
user792677.

Comment: Is your question about how to label the axis or how to show the gaps in the data?

Comment: @Eric Skroch, please see the bounty note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scatter plot asks the datasource for x-y pairs of data. There is no requirement that either value follow some sort of sequence or regular pattern. Other plot types work similarly, although the names and number of data fields can vary.

In your example, return 4 from the `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` method. Return the following values from the `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` method. The table assumes your y-values are calculated by a function f(x), but they can of course come from any source. Use the `field` parameter to determine whether the plot is asking for the x- or y- value.

```
Index  X-Value  Y-Value
  0       1       f(1)
  1       3       f(3)
  2       9       f(9)
  3      10      f(10)
```